# Django will run the function content twice when using render

Tags: django, python-3.x, render

I am sorry that my English is not good. My problem is that refreshing the page in Google Chrome will cause the function with render to run twice But run it once in the Firefox browser. I don't know if this is a problem with Google Chrome or something else?（I hope to get help, thank you）

```
def add_teacher(request):
    Teacher.objects.create(username='zhangs',avatar='https://static-image.xfz.cn/11.jpg',jobtitle='a',profile='b')
    print('==')
    return render(request,'course/course_index.html')
```

Both Google and Firefox run the same content.

Two teachers' data will be created when Google Chrome refreshes the page, But only one piece of data is created when Firefox is running. Pycharm will also print two ‘==’ content when Google runs. Print one on Firefox.

Comment: That could be a problem with your Chrome browser. You need to check if there is any plug gin that causing the issue, also its a bad idea to create an instance in GET request. get requests should be idempotent

Comment: Close the brower and then open. Restart django development server. Hope, it'll work.

Comment: `Two teachers' data will be created` - `GET` should not mean data alterations, do this on `POST`/`PUT` only. Also consider using unique constraints on some fields to limit number of identical rows. Also you might want to use `get_or_create` to avoid dup creation.

Comment: Something is causing the URL to be requested twice. It could be a bad image or JS link, or it could be the favicon. Check your console to see what requests are being made. (But also, as others have noted, you shouldn't create data on GET, only POST.)

Comment: I don't know if it is wrong to create data on GET, thank you for your reminder.